# shell script to pass table name as a parameter in sqlplus?

Tags: shell, unix, sqlplus

I have a file called table.txt which stores the table names. I want the sql update query to take the table name one by one from my table.txt file. My code is as follows:

```
while read LINE1; do
`sqlplus username/pwd@tname <<END |sed '/^$/d'
set head off;
set feedback off;
update &LINE1 set enterprise_id = '1234567890' where enterprise_id is NULL;
update &LINE1 set sim_inventory_id ='1234567890';
COMMIT;
exit;
END`
done < table.txt
```

it gives an error sqlplus not found. Can you please tell what is wrong?

Comment: Why the backticks? Is the location of SQL\*Plus in your PATH environment variable, and has that been exported?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes everything is fine with connection. the error is in passing the table name.

Comment: "sqlplus not found" is nothing to do with passing the table name. It can't find the `sqlplus` binary. Give the full path to that binary, or check your PATH is set and exported properly, either in your script or in the shell you're calling the script from. (Exporting isn't really necessary if you're setting it in the script, if you remove the backticks).

Comment: ok. then how to correct it?

Comment: temp_fsm=`sqlplus -S pgu_app/fred99@pudb01p <<END |sed '/^$/d'
    set head off;
    set feedback off;
    select from_fsm_id from rt_signals where to_fsm_id in (
    select fsm_id from rt_process_log where severity ='ERROR' 
    and line_content ='Unexpected error happened: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("PGUSAGE"."FIN_MTMK_RATEDCDR"."SIM_INVENTORY_ID")'
    and fsm_id in (select fsm_id from rt_fsm_structures where fsm_name    = 'MTMK' and fsm_type= 'FinalDataLoader'
    and suspended = 'Y' ));
    exit;
    END`----- it works fine. here also I have backticks. :)

Comment: Please don't dump code into comments, that isn't what they are for. That has backticks because you're assigning the output from that to the variable, which you are not doing in the example in the question. If that works then you're running that in the shell, or in a script which sets the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with passing the table names. The "sqlplus not found" error means it cannot find that binary executable, so it isn't getting as far as trying to connect or run the SQL commands.

Your shell script can only see environment variables from the calling shell if they were exported. If you've modified your PATH to include the location of the `sqlplus` binary then you may not have exported it; add `export PATH` after you set it.

Or you can set the script up to not rely on the shell environment.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/installation
export PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

while read LINE1; do
sqlplus username/pwd@tname <<END |sed '/^$/d'
set head off;
set feedback off;
update &LINE1 set enterprise_id = '1234567890' where enterprise_id is NULL;
update &LINE1 set sim_inventory_id ='1234567890';
COMMIT;
exit;
END
done < table.txt
```

Incidentally, updating the same table twice isn't necessary; you could do:

```
update &LINE1 set enterprise_id = nvl(enterprise_id, '1234567890'),
  sim_inventory_id ='1234567890';
```

It would also be quicker to create a list of all the update statements from your file contents and run them all in a single SQL*Plus session, so you aren't repeatedly creating and tearing down connections. But that's outside the scope of what you asked.

Comment: but Alex I wrote a select query which is working just above this code. but only this gives an error: SQL*PLUS:: Not Found

Comment: @vartikadhupar - the backticks are creating another level of shell. If you aren't exporting the PATH (how many times can I say that?) then it won't be visible to that subshell. If removing the backticks doesn't resolve the problem then edit the question to show the whole script if it isn't too long, but at least the relevant bits including the previous query and any variables you set and/or export.

Comment: I got the problem. Its not related to exporting ORACLE path. When I bind the query to a variable, it yields result. thanks for your comments as well :)